# How to use Expressions in Measures in Schema Workbench?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, workbench, mondrian, saiku

I have a problem, because I want to distinct-count only those rows where ***durationminutes*** is more than 15. I left the column empty because I created this column through case-when in Expression. But when I try to make my cube work in Saiku, it gives me an error.

[image][image]

There's no problem with the cube itself. I have a similar distinct-count but without any conditions, just for the ***main entry id**, it works perfectly well*. Also I am not sure how Measures work with avg-aggregation, it just gives me an error in the cube itself, showing there's something wrong... I guess it needs Expression, too, but I have no idea what to write there. I tried to find anything about it, but there's nothing, only common information, without mentioning about Expressions in Measures.